# How to compute probability density fuction of a continuous function and then expected value of it?

Tags: probability-distributions, expected-value

I have this discontinuous function:

$$f(r_i) =
\begin{cases}
1, & \text{if}~ |r_i| < 1.5 \\
0, & \text{if}~ |r_i| >1.5
\end{cases}$$
where $r_i = z_i - a^2_i\hat{x}~$, with $z_i$ being the $i$th column of matrix $z = Hx + e$, which error component $e\sim \mathcal{N}(0, \mathcal{I})$ has a covariance $\mathcal{I}$ being the identity matrix, and $a_i$ is the $i$th column vector of a given matrix $H$.

I want to compute probability density function of it and then expectation value. How can I do that (calculating pdf function of these functions)?

What about this slightly different function below with the same $r_i$ ?
$$f(r_i) =
\begin{cases}
r_i^2,  & \text{if}~ |r_i| < 1.5 \\
(1.5)^2 sgn^2(r_i), & \text{if}~ |r_i| > 1.5
\end{cases}$$

Comment: I really don't know what your $sgn^2(r_i)$ is supposed to mean. If it's the sign (positive, negative) then squaring it makes it totally redundant.

Comment: I mean signum function that it is:sgn(ri)*sgn(ri)

Comment: I kept it because of 0 point. i thought it might be effective.

Comment: another point I should mention is that x_hat is calculated using iteratively reweighted least square